# What is $\Pr(Y\in[\pi,X+\pi]\mid X)$ if $X \sim U(0,\pi)$ and $Y \sim U(0,2\pi)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X \sim U(0,\pi)$ and $Y \sim U(0,2\pi)$ be two uniform independent distributions. What is $\Pr(\left.Y\in[\pi,X+\pi]\right|X)$? Intuitively I know  that the result is $\frac{1}{4}$ but how can I formally derive the density function in order to compute the integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$. If almost surely, $Y=2X$, then $\Pr(Y\in [\pi, \pi+X]|X) = \mathbb I(X>\pi/2)$.
If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $\Pr(Y\in [\pi, \pi+X]|X) = X/(2\pi)$. Indeed, the unconditional probability in this last case is 1/4.  I can't find, off the top of my head, a situation when the conditional probability is 1/4.

Comment: They are independent. What do you mean with $\Pr(Y\in [\pi, \pi+X]|X) = X$?

Comment: I made a small mistake, it's actually $\Pr(Y\in [\pi, \pi+X]|X) = X/(2\pi)$. A conditional probability is not necessarily a deterministic number, in general it is a random variable, in this case equal to the random variable $X/(2\pi)$.

Comment: Interpretation : if you know $X$ (so it is not random for you anymore), and you know that $Y$ is independent of $X$, then your knowledge of $X$ does not change the distribution of $Y$, it is still $\mathcal U([0,2\pi])$. Hence, the probability that $Y$ falls in an interval of length $X$ is $X/(2\pi)$.

Comment: It makes sense, but therefore the probability seems to be $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ and not $\frac{1}{4}$. Right?

Comment: The unconditional probability $\Pr(Y\in[\pi,\pi+X])$ is equal to 1/4. It is also the expectation of the conditional probability:
$$\Pr(Y\in[\pi,\pi+X]) = \mathbb E[\Pr(Y\in[\pi,\pi+X] |X)] = \mathbb E[X/(2\pi)] = \mathbb E[X]/(2\pi) = (\pi/2)/(2\pi) = 1/4$$